# Android - Custom Interpolator Class Reference In Xml

Tags: android, xml

I have written my own custom `interpolator` class .

```
@Override
    public float getInterpolation(float t) {

        return t*t*t;

    }
```

I am doing Fragment slide in and slide out animation .There I want to give the reference of this interpolator class in the xml.

But In the xml I am only able to add android provided interpolators.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate
            android:fromXDelta="594"
            android:startOffset="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
            android:toXDelta="0" 
            android:fillAfter="true"
            android:duration="400"/>



</set>
```

So basically I wanted to know how to give reference of Custom Interpolator class in Xml.

Comment: just use `Animation.setInterpolator()` method

Comment: I know that but I have asked how to give reference in Xml.

Comment: in xml?  no,  it cannot be done in xml

Answer (score -2):

Create your custom interpolator and save it in a XML file in the `res/anim` folder of your project. For example

```
XML file saved at res/anim/my_interpolator.xml:
```

Then where ever you need to use it access it like given below

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@anim/my_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="3.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="3.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="700" />
```

In the `android:interpolator` section of your XML file change your default `@android/` to `@anim/` and choose your custom interpolator.

This works for me. Let me know if you have any trouble. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a sample of my_interpolator.xml ??Thanx

Comment: Basic idea is to override getInterpolation method .

Comment: Thanx and really appreciate your help .But the problem still is the same that only android provided interpolators property can be overriden .In the end the above links also says the same.